# Currency data labels in column chart

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and cannot seem to figure out how to format the data labels against each column to currency.

[image]

I have looked for a solution online and have not been able to find one.  One common suggestion was to ensure that the measure used (that needs to be in currency format) was formatted directly to currency, which is what I had already done.

The Y-axis is in currency format, but the data labels are not - how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a strange one. A possible work around is, I assume you added the labels by checking the check box "show marked labels", to remove the labels by un checking the "show marked labels" box in the pop up when you select the labels marks card.

Then grab your measure pill your using, [Salary Band] from the measures area and drag it into the Labels marks card. You will then be able to manually add a euro sign by selecting the label mark card and in the pop up window next to the "Text" box select the edit option and add it there.

Hope that does the job.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround; it worked and is just what I wanted to achieve.  However, it bugs/concerns me that this didn't work from the onset, or at least be simple enough to implement, similar to how one would expect to do so in Excel.